# Comparing the subset of an array against original array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays, both containing objects, where the common field between them is the name. I want to output the data from these arrays to a simple table. However, as one array is the subset of the other, when filling the table the data isn't in the right place. I would like to fill these gaps with `0`. For example:

```
// Array 1:
[
  { Name: A, Value: 7 }, 
  { Name: B, Value: 13 }, 
  { Name: C, Value: 36 }, 
  { Name: D, Value: 43 }
]

// Array 2:
[
  { Name: A, Value: 3 }, 
  { Name: C, Value: 21 }, 
  { Name: D, Value: 15 }
]
```

At the moment, the output table looks like this:

```
A | 3  | 7
B | 21 | 13
C | 15 | 36
D |    | 43
```

But I would like it to look like this:

```
A | 3  | 7
B | 0  | 13
C | 21 | 36
D | 15 | 43
```

The code I'm using for this is:

```
for(var j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
  var row = "<tr><td>Name : " + array1[j]["Name"] + "</td>" +
    "<td>Name : " + array2[j]["Value"] + "</td>" +
    "<td>Name : " + array1[j]["Value"] + "</td></tr>";
  $("#TABLE").append(row);
}
```

This is just an example and my current code follows the same lines, however, the initial data is being pulled straight from a database and inserted into a JSON array. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just a note, I believe your output tables would actually be missing a row completely by using your code snippet, as `array2` is only 3 items in length. It wouldn't loop through a 4th time to grab the extra element from `array1`. Which poses a question in my eyes: Will `array1` always have "full" data, or is the reverse a possibility, where `array2` has values that `array1` does not?

Comment: Understood, though I still believe the question in my comment will provide us with some important information. You said that one array is a subset of the other, leading me to believe that there will never be a case where `array2` has data that `array1` does not. Is this correct?

Comment: Fixed, It was a typo.

Comment: My understanding of a subset isn't too great, what I mean is that `array2` will never be greater than `array1`. So it may have the same number of items in the array, or it may have less. However, it will never have more. These names that are in `array2` will also always be in `array1`. So `array2` can't contain something that isn't in `array1`. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, instead of just looping through `array1`, is first check to see if that same name is also in `array2`. If it is, you can use that `array2` value, but if its not, you should use 0.

The following code will get you there:

```js
var array1 = [{ Name: "A", Value: 7 }, { Name: "B", Value: 13 }, { Name: "C", Value: 36 }, { Name: "D", Value: 43 }]
var array2 = [{ Name: "A", Value: 3 }, { Name: "C", Value: 21 }, { Name: "D", Value: 15 }]

for(var j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {

  var arrayName = array1[j]["Name"];
  var array1value = array1[j]["Value"];
  var array2value = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
     if (array2[i]["Name"] == arrayName) {
         array2value = array2[i]["Value"];
         break;
     }
  }

  var row = "<tr><td>" + arrayName + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + array1value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + array2value + "</td></tr>";
  $("#TABLE").append(row);
}
```

```css
table tr td, table tr th{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TABLE">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Array1 Val</th>
        <th>Array2 Val</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Admittedly, there are probably more advanced/efficient methods of accomplishing this, though I believe my example favors readability.

Comment: Thanks, this worked really well around my existing code!

Answer (score 0):

As i could understand you want a table with NAME | arr2 | arr1 giving priority to arr1, so try this:

```js
// Array 1:
var arr1 = [{Name: "A",Value: 7}, {Name: "B",Value: 13}, {Name: "C",Value: 36}, {Name: "D",Value: 43}];

// Array 2:
var arr2 = [{Name: "A",Value: 3}, {Name: "C",Value: 21}, {Name: "D",Value: 15}];

var result = arr1.map(function(el1) {
  return "<tr><td>"+ el1.Name +" |</td><td>" + (arr2.filter(function(el2) {
    return el1.Name == el2.Name;
  }).map(function(el2){
    return el2.Value;
  })[0] || 0) + " |</td><td>" + el1.Value + "</td></tr>";
}).join("");

$('#result').html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="result">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rows = $("<tr><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>".repeat(4));

var array1 = [
  { Name: "A", Value: 7 }, 
  { Name: "B", Value: 13 }, 
  { Name: "C", Value: 36 }, 
  { Name: "D", Value: 43 }
]

var array2 = [
  { Name: "A", Value: 3 }, 
  { Name: "C", Value: 21 }, 
  { Name: "D", Value: 15 }
]
for (var i = 0 ; i < array1.length; i++) {
 var idx = array1[i].Name.charCodeAt(0) - "A".charCodeAt(0);
  $(rows[idx]).children(":eq(0)").text(array1[i].Value)
}

for (var i = 0 ; i < array2.length; i++) {
 var idx = array2[i].Name.charCodeAt(0) - "A".charCodeAt(0);
  $(rows[idx]).children(":eq(1)").text(array2[i].Value)
}

$("table").append(rows)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
// for each item in the first array...
array1.forEach(function(item) {
    // try to find a match in the second array
    var item2 = array2.find(function(i) { return i.Name === item.Name; });

    // build out the row HTML, defaulting a value of 0 when match is not found
    var row = "<tr><td>Name : " + item.Name + "</td>" +
    "<td>Name : " + (item2 ? item2.Value : 0) + "</td>" +
    "<td>Name : " + item.Value + "</td></tr>";

    // append row to table
    $("#TABLE").append(row);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way to do this but still wanted to point out that it can be done this way too.

```js
var a=[
  { Name: "A", Value: 7 }, 
  { Name: "B", Value: 13 }, 
  { Name: "C", Value: 36 }, 
  { Name: "D", Value: 43 }
];

var b=[
  { Name: "A", Value: 3 }, 
  { Name: "C", Value: 21 }, 
  { Name: "D", Value: 15 }
];
var temp=a.concat(b);
var output = [];
for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
  var existingNameObj = output.filter(function(v){
   return temp[i]["Name"] == v["Name"];
   });
  if(existingNameObj.length){
    var existingObjIndex = output.indexOf(existingNameObj[0]);
    output[existingObjIndex]["ValueArray"].push(temp[i]["Value"]);
  }else{
    output.push({
      "Name":temp[i]["Name"],
      "ValueArray":[temp[i]["Value"]]
    });
  }
}
for(var j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
  var row = "<tr><td>Name : " + output[j]["Name"] + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + output[j]["ValueArray"][0] + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + (output[j]["ValueArray"][1]|0) + "</td></tr>";
  $("#TABLE").append(row);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TABLE"></table>
```